# Wiring Pi Issue - #!/bin/bash vs #!/bin/sh

Tags: gpio, raspbian-jessie, bash, script, wiringpi

I am working on a project and have an application shell script. For function part, I need the GPIO access, and for that, I am using the standard wiringpi 
package.

The issue I am getting is with the `#!/bin/bash` vs `#!/bin/sh` use

I have been using the `#!/bin/bash` in past in conjunction with the wiringpi function - Raspberry Pi A+

but now when I have switched to the Raspberry Pi Jessie buster July 2019, I am having an issue running the wiring Pi function

for example

```
gpio mode 21 out
gpio -g write 21 0
```

working fine inside script if I use `#!/bin/sh`

but I get warnings for the associative array

Warning:

```
./dataLog.sh: 292: ./dataLog.sh: declare: not found
./dataLog.sh: 295: ./dataLog.sh: Bad substitution
```

Code:

```
Line 291: declare -A status="($(upsc myups | sed 's/\(.*\):\(.*\)/[\1]="\2"/'))"

Line 295: if [[ ${status[device.model]} != "" ]] ; then
```

if I use the `#!/bin/bash`, I do not get any error related to the associative array, but now my GPIO is not working.

I am trying to find the solution to the issue - Where I can use #!/bin/bash shell and wiringpi functions together

Thank you

Comment: I can't see any relevance to wiringPi or the Raspberry Pi.  his seems to be a general script problem.

Comment: Yes, but I can see how the OP might not be able determine that, since there is the mystery of `gpio` not working in one version.  Which is a real mystery.

Comment: @joan The issue is that I was using the same script with the minibian buit, and never had any issue

Comment: Kunal, you need to clarify exactly what you mean by "not working".  How are you running the script?  Are there any errors, or is this deduction based on the physical behaviour?  If the latter, exactly what is that (LEDs, etc)?

Comment: now I have upgraded to the Jessie img and now the same script breaks

Comment: @goldilocks the script is executed at the system restart, it is for NUT server information fetching. 

I never had any issue with this script for more then 5 years , and after upgrade to Jessie Buster Jul 2019 build, I am not able to run my script

Comment: The weird thing is that if I use #!/bin/bash I do not get any warning, but my GPIO function is not working, 

GPIO 21 is status LED which I toggle in every 500 ms

Comment: Okay so you don't actually check for/catch logic or other runtime errors in the script?  My first guess would be `gpio` is not in `$PATH` -- which is unlikely but would throw an explicit "command not found" error.  You can check for stuff like that during intialization with the exit status (`$?`) of `which`, or `test -x` (single square bracket stuff in shell is the same as `test`).  If `gpio` is found but fails, its exit status probably reflects this. Etc.  **You need to do a bit of debugging to determine whether `gpio` is actually being invoked or not.**

Comment: I am a novice on the Linux side, I am not checking for any runtime error. It is a simple script with one associative array to catch the response of "upsc myups" command, which is used to check different variable status/values.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98782/discussion-between-kunal-sonone-and-goldilocks).

Comment: Ah, so this was news to me, but I see that WiringPi is no longer supported as of last month: http://wiringpi.com/wiringpi-deprecated/.  So, I think you are probably on your own here to update the scripts under the hood, using my answer below as a clue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, after fiddling around I am able to resolve the issue.

As per the WiringPi setup guide to set the direction of a gpio u should use

```
    gpio mode 21 out
```

This method works if you are using **#!/bin/sh** shell

But if you want to use **#!/bin/bash** shell then you have to use

```
    gpio -g mode 21 out
```

After, setting up the direction with use of '-g' I am able to control the GPIOs

Comment: In other words this question has nothing to do with bash! `gpio mode 21 out` would set `BCM 5`. It is a simple failure to read the documentation.

Comment: Official Guide States :  gpio -g …

    _The optional -g flag causes pin numbers to be interpreted as 
    BCM_GPIO pin numbers rather than standard wiringPi pin 
    numbers._

And it is true for GPIO R/W, the document does not have anything about the _**MODE**_

Answer (score 2):

Check out this post on the difference between `sh` and `bash`:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash

In summary of key points, `sh` is really a standard and `bash` was originally an implementation of that standard that evolved to have a lot of extensions, some of which caused it to deviate from the standard.

When you do `#!/bin/sh` that usually actually directs you to a `bash` shell, but that's implementation / configuration dependent on your flavor of Linux. (Note the recent trend toward having `sh` point to `dash` in the answer at the link.)  Even when it directs to `bash`, however, `bash` may know that you called it as `sh` and restrict access to the extensions.

So bottom line is that `sh` and `bash` are not equivalent and they may differ in different ways depending on the exact version of Linux that you have.  If you are using `bash` extensions, then specify that you need `bash`. (This seems to be your case.)

Comment: So far the search leads me to the conclusion that the "wiringpi" can only be accessed through the sh shell. Which is making it difficult for me to use the bash functions, which I need for batter part of my script

Comment: I don't know if WiringPi does or does not work from various shells, but the premise of your question seems to be wrong to the extent that you seemed to expect different shells to have the same behavior.  From what I understand in your question, it doesn't seem to be working for you properly in either shell, but it's giving you different symptoms in the two cases.

Comment: I have to edit my question, I want to resolve the issue but not sure about the solution I can use

Comment: As of last month, WiringPi is no longer supported: http://wiringpi.com/wiringpi-deprecated/. You can use this answer as a clue to debug what's happening under the hood, but if some script in there is using extensions (`bash` or otherwise), then you may need to sort that out yourself. Else post more details, Else use something other than WiringPi.

Comment: Thank you Brick for the information, I appreciate that. It seems I have to go back to my old minibian image for now till I resolve this issue.

Comment: "When you do #!/bin/sh that usually actually directs you to a bash shell" that used to be the case, but nowadays Debian-based distros use dash as the default /bin/sh implementation.

Comment: @PeterGreen That's the very next sentence in the answer....